# gcloud run deploy keeps erroring when I add args: '--args: expected one argument'

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run `gcloud run deploy` with the following parameters:

```
gcloud run deploy "$SERVICE_NAME" \
    --quiet \
    --region "$RUN_REGION" \
    --image "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$SERVICE_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA" \
    --platform "managed" \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --args "--privileged"
```

but I keep getting the following error when I add anything to `args` whatsoever:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) argument --args: expected one argument
```

I am obviously using the `args` parameter incorrectly but for the life of me I can't figure out why. The [example in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#command-line_1) uses it exactly as I have done.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Even the example from the docs doesn't work, and returns the same error:

```
gcloud run deploy  \
  --args "--repo-allowlist=github.com/example/example_demo" \
  --args "--gh-webhook-secret=XX" \
```

Answer (score 3):

So, I finally got it working. I'm not sure why I needed to add an `=` as that wasn't specified in the docs, but here's the solution:

```
--args="--privileged"
```

Comment: Associating long flags `--flag` with values with `=` is good practice. I'm this case,  `gcloud`'s command line's (Python's) parser is treating `"--privileged"` as if it were a `gcloud`flag. (as if the quotes weren't present). Using the `=` overcomes this. It's either `gcloud`, its parser or the versions you've installed. Please report your feedback to Google.